# Highcharts packed bubble chart not working for negative values

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am using High charts packed bubble chart and I need to show different sizes of bubbles according to its value (negative values). It is working fine when I pass positive values but size of the circle not changing when I pass negative values. Is there any way to show chart with negative values?

[js fiddle link with code example](https://jsfiddle.net/heshanjay/Lbmn60ow/117/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'packedbubble',
        height: '100%'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'TOP Countries'
    },
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}:</b> {point.value}'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        packedbubble: {
            minSize: '30%',
            maxSize: '80%',
            zMin: 0,
            zMax: 1000,
            layoutAlgorithm: {
                splitSeries: false,
                gravitationalConstant: 0.02
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{series.name}',
                filter: {
                    property: 'y',
                    operator: '>',
                    value: 250
                },
                style: {
                    color: 'black',
                    textOutline: 'none',
                    fontWeight: 'normal'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'ASEAN',
        data: [{
            name: "ASEAN",
            value: -88.2
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'KOR ',
        data: [{
            name: "KOR",
            value: -605.2
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'CHN ',
        data: [{
            name: "CHN",
            value: -427233.7
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'ISA ',
        data: [{
            name: "ISA",
            value: -355.39
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'ANZ ',
        data: [{
            name: "ANZ ",
            value: -3331.4
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'JP ',
        data: [{
            name: "JP1",
            value: -22470857.0
        },{
            name: "JP2",
            value: -21470857.0
        }]
    }]
});
```

**graph with negative values**

[image: graph with negative values]

**graph with positive values**
[image: graph with positive values]

Answer (score 0):

Properties `zMin` and `zMax` are not a part of official `packedbubble` series API, but they are internally used and work as in `bubble` series.

```
plotOptions: {
    packedbubble: {
        minSize: '30%',
        maxSize: '80%',
        //zMin: 0,
        //zMax: 1000,
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vro2wzL4/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.packedbubble

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.zMin

Comment: in here -21470857.0 circle is smaller than -88.2 can we do other way round? I need -21470857.0 as big circle and --88.2 should be small

Comment: Hi @heshjse, Ok, so maybe reverse the values to positive and change `pointFormat` in tooltip? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o8kq43ay/